# Copied my style code from html to a css page but its coming up with errors

Tags: html, css

I have attached the code in question, for the exercise we had to copy code into the html page. Once we had completed that we had to copy and paste into a css file. Once I done that it has come up with EXPECTED Colon & EXPECTED RBRACE errors.

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/*This is how you write style comments in CSS */

/* CSS Styles in the head are called Inline Styles */

html { height:101%; }
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:12px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#333; /* equal to Grey */
    text-align:center; /* Used by older IE browsers to centre page */
    }

/* These are the styles for text */

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {padding,0px;font-weight:500; font-family:
Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century
Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif; clear:both;}   
/* watch for the drop down menu when typing font-families: and choose from the convenient list offered*/

h1{font-size:60px;}
h2{font-size:40px;}
h3{font-size:24px;}
h4{font-size:20px;}
h5{font-size:18px;}
h6{font-size:16px;}

section {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#F60;  /* orange*/
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:10;
    }
article {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFCC00;   /*gold*/
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:200px;
    z-index:11;
    }

/*a # is how you denote a div in CSS */

#dBox{
        width:30%;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#FF0000;
        border: #000 solid 1px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        z-index:12;
    }

#dBox h2{
        width:auto;
        height:100px;
        background-color:transparent;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family: arial "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad 
        Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvatica, Arial, sans-
        serif;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:150px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        z-index13;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where you have errors:

1. You have placed `,` instead of `:` after padding.

   `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {padding,0px;`
2. You have missed a semicolon after z-index.

   `z-index13;`

Comment: Cool thank you, now I can move forward and try to figure out why the styles aren't being transferred over. No colour or the boxes have displayed in preview mode in the browser, but displays fine in dreamweaver preview window whilst coding. Thanks again @Himanshu